# getting the sprite attached to a SKPhysicsBody

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I'm animating a sprite, and when it touches another one, a physics contact function is called. Than, in this function, I'm trying to get the sprite with touched the other. Its body is bodyA but it's a SKPhysicsBody, and it can not be converted as a SKSpriteNode. Do you have any ideas?

The function is correctly called when contact, I just try to get the sprite which body makes the contact. The final idea is getting the  actions attached to the sprite with I'm looking for but I suppose when you have the sprite it's easy.

```
    let shootCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
    let enemyCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1


    // Declaration of the SKPhysicsBody of the sprite which will touch the other one
    sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: (20))
    sprite.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    sprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = shootCategory
    sprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = shootCategory | enemyCategory
    sprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = shootCategory | enemyCategory
    sprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

    // Declaration of the SKPhysicsBody of the sprite which will be touched
    sprite.run(SKAction.group([moveAction, fadeInAction]))
    sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: (20))
    sprite.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    sprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = enemyCategory
    sprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = shootCategory | enemyCategory
    sprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = shootCategory | enemyCategory
    sprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false


    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == enemyCategory) && (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == shootCategory){

        // I tried this to get the sprite which the bodyB is attached to but it doesn't even build
        let sprite: SKSpriteNode = sprite.contact.bodyB
        contact.bodyA.removeAction(forKey: "moveToAction")
    }
}
```

Comment: Apple documents exist for a reason, I would suggest using them https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520049-node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution with is really simple:

```
    let Node = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode
```